# How does linux choose which gateway to use if there are multiple defaults?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I use `NetworkManager` to connect to VPN servers. My VPN has multiple servers, so I configured a dozen or so profiles. `NetworkManager` allows you to connect to multiple VPNs at once; if I do this, the routing table can end up with multiple default routes.

1. What does Linux do in this situation?
2. Is there any way to configure it so that it'll pick faster gateways?

Example (partial table):

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         10.8.8.1        0.0.0.0         UG    50     0        0 tun0
0.0.0.0         10.7.7.1        0.0.0.0         UG    51     0        0 tun1
0.0.0.0         10.8.8.1        0.0.0.0         UG    52     0        0 tun2
0.0.0.0         10.7.7.1        0.0.0.0         UG    53     0        0 tun3
0.0.0.0         10.8.8.1        0.0.0.0         UG    54     0        0 tun4
0.0.0.0         192.168.50.1    0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 enp0s31f6
```

Comment: I would very much like to know, though it may be better suited for  the [Linux&Unix stackexchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: How did you print the routing table? What does `netstat -anr` and `ip rule show` (and `ip route list table TTT` where TTT are all tables mentioned by `ip rule show`) outputs? Are there situation when several tunX interfaces are up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your extra gateways have different metric (and possibly have different tables, post `ip rule show` and `ip route list table TTT` where TTT are all tables mentioned by `ip rule show`). Metric is documented in man 8 route http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/route.8.html

```
   metric M
          set the metric field in the routing table (used by routing
          daemons) to M. If this option is not specified the metric for
          inet6 (IPv6) address family defaults to '1', for inet (IPv4)
          it defaults to '0'. You should always specify an explicit
          metric value to not rely on those defaults - they also differ
          from iproute2.

   Metric The 'distance' to the target (usually counted in hops).
```

Rules are https://serverfault.com/questions/648276/routing-selection-specificity-vs-metric:

> Single routing table... In this case, the kernel chooses:
>
> - the most specific route;
> - if there are multiple equally specific routes, the one with the smallest kernel metric.

So, when there are no multiple routing tables, **linux will use only one** reachable **gateway with lowest metric** (it probably will not use gateway from offline network interface).

> Is there any way to configure it so that it'll pick faster gateways?

No, when the gateway is not used, you can't check how fast it is. Also you can't afford personal computer to have [own AS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autonomous_system_(Internet)) to legally have several gateways which can connect your single IP to the internet. (So, picking different gateway will break all your TCP and UDP connections, as you will use different IP address in the internet).